# Recovering a build

Tags: linux, cmake, chromium, ninja

While building chromium (ninja) my workstation crashed. After reboot, there were a number of
empty .o files. I tried a fix by making small changes to the respective .cc file (adding stubs
`//stub is a comment that should trigger a recompile for this file` to every file that failed to link and deleting the empty .o files).

Later, however, libchrome failed to link without (class name not defined). Now, I could simply look for these classes, change them and try to retrigger a rebuild by ninja, but chromium is massive, really massive.

Do you know any ninja tricks?

Comment: Delete any 0-size .o files?

Comment: Is it really worth salvaging the build? Would seem less trouble and more reliable to completely clean the build and do a full rebuild.